# BAPI_MDDATASET_CREATE_OBJECT MDX Query

Tags: mdx, bapi, sap-bw

I would like to make a BAPI call from Java to the BAPI `BAPI_MDDATASET_CREATE_OBJECT`.

Therefore I want to use the following MDX Query:

```
SELECT
[0DISTR_CHAN].Members ON COLUMNS,
[0MATERIAL].Members ON ROWS
FROM [$/PKG/AB_C01]
```

Because the Parameter "COMMAND_TEXT" is to short I made 4 entries like this:
[image]

Now I run the BAPI and get a DATASETID in return. I use this id with the next BAPI `BAPI_MDDATASET_CHECK_SYNTAX`.

But now I get an exception:

> `E RS_EXCEPTION 000 Es ist eine Ausnahme Aufgetreten.`
>
> [image]

English Version:

> `E RS_EXCEPTION 000 An exception has occurred.`
>
> [image]

Why is this so?

This MDX query seems to be OK, because in transaction `MDXTEST` this query is working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks ok - do you need a semi-colon at the end `FROM [$/PKG/AB_C01];`

Comment: I tried it, but same exception.

Comment: what is the MESSAGE? "Es ist..." Can you please translate to English.

Comment: added an english version of the exception

Comment: oh - its not too descriptive!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem only with c# and sap connector.
I solved it. Need to use all commands in one context:

```
RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(destination);
Create_Object();
CheckSyntax();
etc.
RfcSessionManager.EndContext(this.destination);
```

Comment: Much better ;-) Context is the missing key. No I got a new exception... Syntaxerror, but this is something I can wor on. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a large table that is n * m where n are the number of columns and m is the number of rows:

```
SELECT
[0DISTR_CHAN].Members ON COLUMNS,
[0MATERIAL].Members ON ROWS
FROM [$/PKG/AB_C01]
```

n = number of members in this dimension `[0DISTR_CHAN]` + 1
m = number of members in this dimension `[0MATERIAL]`

This is not an answer but maybe will help to discover if the mdx is the problem. If you simplify the above to just a single member on rows, and a single member on columns do you still get an error?

```
SELECT
  {[0DISTR_CHAN].[0DISTR_CHAN].[someMemberY]} ON COLUMNS,
  {[0MATERIAL].[0MATERIAL].[someMemberX]} ON ROWS
FROM [$/PKG/AB_C01];
```